# Does Strategy pattern involve modifying every subclass?

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

Consider a super class `Animal`, inherited by multiple subclasses(`Dog` / `Bird`). On their instantiation, objects have their local state & behavior:

[image]

---

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) says:

> The strategy pattern
>
> - defines a family of algorithms,
> - encapsulates each algorithm, and
> - makes the algorithms interchangeable within that family.

---

If a requirement demands to add a new behavior(`fly()`) in super class `Animal`,  then use  Strategy pattern, to create new family of algorithm(`CantFly`/ `ItFly`) and encapsulate these algorithms in `setFlyingAbility()`/`tryToFly()`, to attain minimal code changes in existing class hierarchy, with below changes:

[image]

where `ItFyls` and `CantFly` are family of algorithms for new  behavior(`fly`) that are used by subclasses(`Dog` / `Bird`) interchangeably, with below code changes

[image]

---

Association of type **Composition**, at crux, is helping to add new behavior in super class by minimizing code changes in super/sub class relationship, shown below,

```
class Animal{
    ....
    Flys flyingType;
    ....
    public String tryToFly(){
       return flyingType.fly();
    }
    public void setFlyingAbility(Flys newFlyType){
      flyingType = newFlyType;
    }
}
```

---

**Question:**

To add a new behavior(`fly()`) in super class(`Animal`), Does Strategy pattern involves modifying every subclass(`Dog`/`Bird`) constructor? Can modification of subclass get avoided?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/tree/master/5_Design_pattern/Design_pattern_types/Behavioral_pattern/Strategy_pattern) are changes after inputs from, Brandon Arnold

Comment: @FrankHileman Please provide your comments here, as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of the Strategy Pattern is fine, but I do not think your example is a good illustration of the problem Strategy Pattern is solving.

Consider sorting. Given an array of comparable items, we choose among many different sorting algorithms (or, "strategies"). One common use case of the strategy pattern is used to run the algorithms in parallel, for example, until the first one terminates. Databases have a similar approach to finding the most efficient method of performing a query, during the optimization phase.

Your OO analogy with Dog/Bird inheriting from Animal doesn't quite fit this, in my view, because the `fly()` strategy that you choose depends on whether the input is a dog or a bird.

A better fit for your situation is the idea of a virtual function. In such a case, the base class Animal declares the function signature, and defers the implementation to inheriting classes.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) api?

Comment: @user1787812 No, more like this one: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Comment: Brandon, I wrote some code [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/tree/master/5_Design_pattern/Design_pattern_types/Behavioral_pattern/Strategy_pattern), after reading the answer. Please acknowledge on my understanding

Comment: @user1787812 the line you highlight with a red square in your constructors is practically identical to the purpose of a virtual function in a derived class

Comment: After reading your answer, Using strategy pattern, I wrote sorting code [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/tree/master/5_Design_pattern/Design_pattern_types/Behavioral_pattern/Strategy_pattern) which is different example.

Comment: @user1787812 and again, no, I think you are not showing what the Strategy Pattern is intended for. I have the same answer. Strategy Pattern is about organize differing strategies to deal with the same thing. Dog and Bird are not the same thing.

Comment: @user1787812 Your github is definitely more along the lines of my idea of Strategy Pattern!!

Comment: Yes, I have single thing `SorterImpl` that deals with different strategies(`strategy.*`). As per the code in github, Am i missing something in understanding of Strategy pattern?

Comment: Yes, that is the right idea

Comment: How *dealing with strategies* different from *dependency injection*? because `SorterImpl()` is injected with implementation(`new BubbleSortAlgo()`) to work with?

Comment: Strategy Pattern is totally compatible with dependency injection. Strategy Pattern does not dictate how a context type is parameterized into the strategy implementation, it only dictates that a base strategy class (e.g. SortStrategy) specifies the context type (e.g. List<Comparable>) that its implementation strategy classes (e.g. BubbleSort) must handle. Dependency Injection is a different subject.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but I think your answer is somewhat missing the point of the question. *"because the fly() strategy that you choose depends on whether the input is a dog or a bird."* - sure it depends on this, on what else should it depend? Ok, the example looks contrived, of course, but the fact there are two inheritance hierarchies is simply a "bridge pattern", and the design won't become better by moving parts of the strategy into the left hierarchy and intermixing it - which is essentially what the last paragraph of your answer says.

Comment: Thanks, doc. My last paragraph is to suggest only that what he is doing is not a Strategy Pattern. But I think you make a good observation to relate his idea to Bridge Pattern. "On what else should it depend?" Performance, usually, but the point of a Strategy Pattern is that there are different "strategies" of reaching the same result. Flying and not flying are not the same result.

Comment: Sorting is also a bad example, though, as you can always use the lambda function unless you use an old language like Java 5. A program that supports different serialization formats is a better example, as serialization format consists of two functions that are related. Another one is a random number generator, where you can seed and return a random number of various sizes.

Answer (score 0):

### The "strategy pattern" is a red herring here!

There is an existing class hierarchy (of animals), and one tries to make the code more SOLID (in this case specifically SRP and OCP conform). Then the refactoring causes the necessity to touch every constructor in the hierarchy - but **that is quite normal** when making a non-solid class hierarchy more SOLID, and it has absolutely **nothing** to do the specific approach here is "Strategy". The real reason is, refactoring a more complex codebase involves more effort than refactoring a simpler one - that is IMHO not very surprising!

The "Strategy" pattern requires always one or more places in the program where the specific strategy subclass has to be picked, or changed (maybe it changes at runtime, maybe not). This is part of the business logic, and the "correct" place is case-dependent. When it is introduced into a simple context (like a test class without a class hierarchy), there are typically less things to be changed than when it gets introduced into a more complex context like a class hierarchy. However, the reason for this is the **complexity of the context**, not the pattern.

In this specific example, it makes sense to make the decision about the strategy in the constructor of the different animals - the association `Dog - CantFly`, `Bird - ItFlys` must be somewhere, and since the correct strategy can be picked by the kind of animal, by general knowledge, and it won't change during the lifetime of each object, the constructor is not the worst place to implement it.

So yes, making this code more SOLID involves changing the constructors **at the time you introduce the pattern into the code**, no less, no more (in real code, you will probably have to refactor more things in the Animal class hierarchy for introducing the pattern). Note the point such refactorings is not to avoid changes to the code *before* it got introduced, but  *after*.

Comment: Wrt your first point, strategy is picked in my github [code](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/tree/master/5_Design_pattern/Design_pattern_types/Behavioral_pattern/Strategy_pattern) at client place, test package. Unlike, in my query, where strategy is picked in subclass constructor. So, isn't github code better fit for strategy pattern and virtual function for above query.

Comment: @user1787812: see my edit.

Comment: Touching constructor in hierarchy doesn't look normal to me, despite strategy pattern allows me to that or not. Because it takes time to at least to know that I did not miss any subclass after finding some 40+ odd subclass/subsubclass(say some GUI component), where the constructor need to get updated.

Comment: @user1787812: I don't know how I can make this clearer without repeating myself: when you refactor a non-solid code base containing a class hierarchy with 40 subclasses, you might have to touch all those 40 classes. That has **absolutely nothing** to with the strategy pattern, it would be the same if you, for example, change the naming scheme of the classes, or just move duplicate code from the 40 subclasses to the base class, or introduce a constructor parameter into all the 40 classes.

Comment: .. and for your specific example: if you had 40 specific animals, you need to tell the program somewhere which of them can fly and which not. This is something *you* know, but the program cannot know beforehand. Encoding this information into the specific animal subclass is IMHO the natural, right thing. And if the information was not coded there beforhand, you have to add it afterwards, no chance to avoid changes to the 40 subclasses.